# Two primary keys but not a composite, what is this sort of relationship called?

Tags: primary-key, denormalization, terminology

I am integrating employee/position data with another system.

The first system is HR. It has an Employee table and a Positions table. The second system tracks office space and tracks who the office belongs to. It uses one table [em] to store both employees and position data.

If an employee changes position then the position id changes. If the position becomes vacant and a new employee fills the position then employee id is changed.

Both position id and employee ID act like primary keys for this table. I am trying to figure out if there is a name for this type of relationship in a database terminology?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called a composite key.

It doesn't matter how you use a composite key. If two pieces of data uniquely identify a row, it's called a composite key. In fact, the use case you're defining is almost always the use case of a composite key.

They're *usually* natural keys (having both fields related to the data), rather than surrogate keys (having both fields independent and abstract from the data). A store location, and product ID is the canonical example of a natural composite key. You're just using employees.

If, by chance, you mean to ask if both inputs used in the composite key have a name when they have a `UNIQUE` property, then no.. You *can* do it, but even in your case it's a bit awkward right? I mean, what if one employee is managing two spaces?

```
CREATE TABLE em ( emid serial PRIMARY KEY, name text, position text );
CREATE TABLE space ( spaceid serial PRIMARY KEY, owner text );
CREATE TABLE em_space (
  emid    int REFERENCES em,
  spaceid int REFERENCES space,
  PRIMARY KEY (emid, spaceid)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

If there two different columns, each of which by itself could be used as a primary key for the table, we say there are two candidate keys.

One candidate key is chosen as *the* primary key. The other candidate keys which were not chosen can be referred to as alternate keys.

Any key can be a single column or a combination of columns. Keys made from more than one column are called composite keys. A column may be part of more than one key. For example candidate keys may be (col_a, col_b), (col_a, col_c), (col_d); col_a is in more than one candidate key. The first two of these are composite candidate keys, the last is not.